# Dynamic replacement of URL text with a hyperlink

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a `v-data-table` component which cells are filled with text containing URLs: "Text with URL https://stackoverflow.com that I'd like to replace with hyperlink"
How can I dynamically replace all these URLs inside text with `a`-tags? The rest of the text except the URLs should remain unchanged.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :single-expand="singleExpand"
    :expanded.sync="expanded"
    item-key="id"
    show-expand
  >
    <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
      <td :colspan="headers.length">
        {{ item.text }}
      </td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  data: () => ({
    singleExpand: false,
    expanded: [],
    headers: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    urlify(text) {
      const urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
      return text.replace(urlRegex, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
    },
  },
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to output real HTML, you will need to use the `v-html` directive.
You already have the `urlify(text)` method in your script section to convert text to URL. A simple use case of this directive with a method is:

```
 <td :colspan="headers.length" v-html="urlify(item.text)">
   </td>
```

For more information, you can read the [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html).